# Is there a way to return custom data to a prompt after interrupting it?

Tags: node.js, nlp, botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I hope I can be clear on this question.
My problem is that I want to use simple Luis triggered dialogs just to signal back the intents/entities to a given current dialog.

i.e I want to decouple the triggering dialogs from my business dialogs, defining dialogs that their only function is to be triggered and return relevant data, for example:

```
bot.dialog('NegativeAnswerTriggeredDialog', [
    (session, args, next) => {
        var response = { type: 'bool', value: false, index: 1, entity: 'No', score: 1};
        session.endDialogWithResult({ response:response });
    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'NegativeAnswer',
    onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
        session.beginDialog(args.action, args);
    }
});
```

So, please note that I just prepare some object and then I endDialogWithResult to hand this object to the previous dialog.

The issue is that the prompt doesn't recognize this object, or the format of this object, Im not sure. Is there a way to return it in a way that it is accepted as a valid input to the prompt?

BTW, The goal I want to achieve here is to allow the user to answer a prompt with natural language.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that the prompt type you are dealing with is `Prompt.confirm` based on the `NegativeAnswerTriggeredDialog` dialog you're attempting to pass.

The problem is `triggerAction` as per [the BotBuilder Handle User Actions documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-actions?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#bind-a-triggeraction) is it clears the Dialog stack by default.  From the docs:

> Binding a triggerAction to a dialog registers it to the bot. Once triggered, the triggerAction will clear the dialog stack and push the triggered dialog onto the stack. This action is best used to switch between topic of conversation or to allow users to request arbitrary stand-alone tasks. If you want to override the behavior where this action clears the dialog stack, add an onSelectAction option to the triggerAction.

You would want to use `customActions` instead, which bind directly to the bot and not to a Dialog object.

Consider my code sample where I have dialogs for both `Prompt.confirm` and `Prompt.choice`:

```
bot.dialog('GreetingDialog', [
    (session) => {
        session.send('You reached the Greeting intent. You said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
        builder.Prompts.confirm(session, "Would you like to learn more?");
    }, (session, results) => {
        console.log(results.response);
        if (results.response) {
            session.endDialog("You're doing your part!");
        } else if (!results.response) {
            session.endDialog("Awwww....  no fun.");
        } else {
            session.endDialog("Something else is going on here.");
        }
    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'Greeting'
});

bot.dialog('HelpDialog',[
    (session) => {
        session.send('You reached the Help intent. You said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Pick something colorful", ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue"]);
    }, (session, results) => {
        switch(results.response.entity) {
            case "Red":
                session.endDialog("Red it is.");
                break;
            case "Yellow": 
                session.endDialog("Yellow it is.");
                break;
            case "Blue":
                session.endDialog("Blue it is.")
                break;
            default:
                session.endDialog("I have no idea what that is.");
        }
    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'Help'
});

bot.customAction({
    matches: 'NegativeAnswer',
    onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
        session.endDialogWithResult({response: false});
    }
});

bot.customAction({
    matches: "PositiveAnswer",
    onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
        session.endDialogWithResult({response: true});
    }
});

bot.customAction({
    matches: "Red",
    onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
        session.endDialogWithResult({response: { index: 0, entity: 'Red', score: 1 }});
    }
});

bot.customAction({
    matches: "Yellow",
    onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
        session.endDialogWithResult({response: { index: 1, entity: 'Yellow', score: 1 }});
    }
});

bot.customAction({
    matches: "Blue",
    onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
        session.endDialogWithResult({response: { index: 2, entity: 'Blue', score: 1 }});
    }
});
```

`Prompt.confirm` is a Yes/No prompt, and thus maps "Yes" to `true` and "No" to `false`.  It doesn't take the object you were attempting to pass in the code sample.  In my test run, based on the LUIS Intents I set up, "Yep", "Of course", and "Yeah" all mapped to "Yes."  "Negative", "Nah", and "I don't think so" (among other variations) mapped to "No."  Your setup may differ on the LUIS intent side.

`Prompt.choice`, on the other hand, expects the response objects as included in the "Red", "Blue", and "Yellow" example `customAction`s.  In this case, I set up possible utterances of "crimson", "maroon", "amber", "cerulean", etc. for the appropriate intents.

As long as you have the expected possible answers for each of the Intents, it should map to the proper answer.